# How to customize module name for Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am a newbie as far as Sphinx is concern. My project structure is as follow:

- argparse_actions/

  - argparse_actions/

    - __init__.py
    - folder_actions.py
    - ip_actions.py
  - doc/

    - _build/
    - index.rst ==> This is the starting point, home page, or root doc.
    - and more...

__init__.py looks like this:

```
from folder_actions import *
from ip_actions import *
```

*folder_actions.py* looks like this:

```
'''
Folder Actions
==============

This module implements some reusable custom actions.

.. autoclass:: FolderExistsAction
.. autoclass:: FolderCreateAction
   :members:

'''

# The rest of the code
```

The generate HTML document looks fine except for this part:

class `folder_actions`.**FolderCreateAction**( ... )

I know that the `folder_actions` module prefix is correct, but I want to change it to use the package name instead, like this:

class `argparse_actions`.**FolderCreateAction**( ... )

Is there a way for me to achieve this?

## Update

- The root document is in `doc/index.rst`
- If I move the docstring from `folder_actions.py` to `__init__.py`, then the doc will look like this:

  ```
  class __init__.FolderCreateAction( ... )
  ```
- FYI, my project is now on [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/htv2013/argparse_actions)

## Update 2

I don't know why my changes are not pushed to BitBucket, but that irrelevant. please take a look at the same project, pushed to [GitHub](https://github.com/htv2012/argparse_actions). I appreciate your help, *mzjn*.

Answer (score 4):

After a few months of hiatus, I finally figured out the solution: by adding the following line to the docstring of `folder_actions.py` and `ip_action.py` modules:

```
.. module:: argparse_actions
```

Preferably, this line should be the first line of the module docstring.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31594545/13945013) answer which provides a solution.

You can modify your `__init__.py` file to:

```py
from folder_actions import *
from ip_actions import *

__all__ = ['FolderCreateAction']
```

This lets Sphinx know you want `FolderCreateAction` to be part of the public API for the package, and will render it is `argparse_actions.FolderCreateAction` in the documentation.