# How to make Sphinx Respect Importing Classes Into Package with __init__.py

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a package:

- foo

  - foo.py
  - bar.py
  - __init__.py

foo.py has a class Foo. In __init__.py I import class Foo so users can do:

```
from foo import Foo
```

Sphinx rightly documents Foo as foo.foo.Foo, which is right but confusing to users. How do I get Sphinx to document it as foo.Foo?

It's also important to get the overall module documentation associated with the right module.

Sphinx documents something called:

```
..module:: module.name
```

but when I use it in the first comment in a `foo.py` file, the doc is still attributed to `foo.foo`.

Comment: Perhaps you can use this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31594545/407651

Answer (score 4):

The value of the `__module__` attribute is the name of the module in which a class/function/method was defined (see https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html). The attribute is writable so it can be redefined in __init__.py:

```
Foo.__module__ = "foo"
```

Now if you use `.. automodule:: foo`, the qualified name of the `Foo` class will be shown as `foo.Foo` in the generated module documentation.

---

As an alternative to `__module__`-fiddling, you can use `autoclass` instead of `automodule`.

`.. autoclass:: foo.Foo` will produce the wanted output.

Comment: Does it have to be \__init__.py? I tried to do it at the point of the definition itself, and it didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: @bmargulies: In the little "Foo" example that I created based on the file structure in the original question, it works as described. And the `Foo.__module__ = "foo"` line can be put in either \__init__.py or in foo.py. I cannot say why it does not work for you.

Comment: Would you expect me to have run sphinx-apidoc again after adding the `__module__` settings? I am using a variation on this that reflects my particular structure. I'll try running sphinx-apidoc again.

Comment: @bmargulies: I did not use sphinx-apidoc. I just created a very small project that includes an .rst file that has `.. automodule:: foo` in it. This allowed me to verify that `__module__` can be manipulated to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31594545/13945013) answer for a solution.

In your case, modify your `__init__.py` file to:

```py
# This lets you use foo.foo.Foo as foo.Foo in your code.
from .foo import Foo

# This lets Sphinx know you want to document foo.foo.Foo as foo.Foo.
__all__ = ['Foo']
```

Comment: Sphinx just outputs "class foo.Foo: An alias of class foo.foo.Foo" and does not document any members.