# Python Sphinx documenting public interface of a package

Tags: python, package, python-sphinx

I have a Python package which contains submodules. Currently, my intention is to allow usage of functionality what the package exports, e.g.:

```
package_X
+-- __init__.py
+-- submodule_A.py
+-- submodule_B.py
```

Submodules are implementation details. Everything the user of the package needs to know is exported in the `__init__.py` file.

Now when building documentation with Sphinx, I get TOC and documentation as follows:

```
package_X

  Submodules
    submodule_A.py
    submodule_B.py
```

Is there any setting or directive I can write to `__init__.py` or `submodule_*.py` to make public stuff appear as if it were directly in `package_X`? I am also ready to modify `conf.py` to make that work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Sphinx Respect Importing Classes Into Package with \_\_init\_\_.py](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096187/how-to-make-sphinx-respect-importing-classes-into-package-with-init-py)