# Python: Sphinx references to classes imported at package level

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I want to document a Python package using Sphinx. Let's assume the package consists of two modules and has the following structure:

```
my_package
    __init__.py
    mod_a.py
        class_a_1
        class_a_2
    mod_a.py
        class_b_1
        class_b_2
```

To make all classes available to the user at the package level, the `__init__.py` contains the following lines:

```
from .mod_a import class_a_1, class_a_2
from .mod_b import class_b_1, class_b_2
```

Currently, I generate an API documentation of my classes using an rst file with the following lines:

```
.. automodule:: my_package.mod_a
   :members:
   :undoc-members:

.. automodule:: my_package.mod_b
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
```

In the resulting documentation the classes are listed e.g. as:

```
class mypackage.mod_a.class_a_1
```

### Question 1

How can I get Sphinx to list the classes in the following two ways:

```
class class_a_1
```

or:

```
class my_package.class_a_1
```

In addition to the API reference, I want to add a tutorial which contains references to the classes and some of their methods. Currently, the following
rst references work:

```
.. currentmodule:: my_package.mod_a
:class:`class_a_1`
```

or:

```
:class:`my_package.mod_a.class_a_1`
```

### Question 2

Is there a way of referencing the classes and methods without defining the full module structure and without using the `.. currentmodule::` directive? In the documentation I often have to switch between the classes from different modules and want to avoid a lot of `.. currentmodule::` directives. Ideally, I would like to use the following ways of referencing:

This sentence uses a references to `` :class:`class_a_1` `` and `` :class:`class_b_1` ``. Alternatively, it would be nice if I could write `` :class:`my_package.class_a_2` `` and `` :class:`my_package.class_b_2` ``.

### Question 3

I want the package to look flat to the user with all classes in the main namespace. Is there anything I could add to my Sphinx documentation file or to the `__init__.py` in order to be able to generate the API doc with a single command like

```
.. automodule:: my_package
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
```

Currently, this command produces an empty page.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please ask one specific question at a time.

Comment: Question 1 is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15115514/407651 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/22096187/407651