# Sphinx cross referencing breaks for inherited objects imported and documented in a parent module

Tags: python, github, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm trying to get my Sphinx documentation build correctly and have cross-references (including those from inherited relations) work right.

In my project, I have a situation which is depicted in the example below, which I replicated for convenience on [this github repo](https://github.com/anjos/sphinx-broken-xref):

```
$ tree .
.
├── a
│   ├── b
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── conf.py
├── index.rst
└── README.md
```

In `a.b.__init__`, I declare classes `A` and `B`. `B` inherits from `A`. In `a.__init__`, I import `A` and `B` like: `from .b import A, B`. The reason I do this in my real projects is to reduce the import paths on modules while keeping implementation of specific classes in separate files.

Then, in my rst files, I *autodoc* module `a` with `.. automodule:: a`. Because `a.b` is just an auxiliary module, I don't *autodoc* it since I don't want to get repeated references to the same classes and not to confuse the user on what they should be really doing. I also set `show-inheritance` expecting `a.B` will have a back link to `a.A`.

If I try to sphinx-build this in nit-picky mode, I'll get the following warning:

```
WARNING: py:class reference target not found: a.b.A
```

If I look at the generated documentation for class `B`, then I verify it is not properly linked against class `A`, which just confirms the warning above.

Question: how do I fix this?

Comment: It works if you add `A.__module__ = "a"` in `a/__init__.py`. This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/22096187/407651.

Comment: Indeed, that works. Care to fill in an answer so I can point to the solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sphinx uses the value of the `__module__` attribute to figure out the name of the module in which a class/function/method was defined (see https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy). Sometimes this is not what you want in the documentation.

The attribute is writable. Your problem can be fixed by adding this line in a/__init__.py:

```
A.__module__ = "a"
```

Comment: Note that this can also be defined at the class level by setting `__module__ = "a"` inside the class definition. Looks a bit cleaner imo.