# How to handle class import aliases in sphinx autodoc

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a project with the following directory structure:

```
project
    datasets
        __init__.py
        foo.py
        bar.py
```

`bar.py` defines a class `Bar` which inherits from the `Foo` class defined in `foo.py`. In `__init__.py`, I have the following import alias:

```
from .foo import Foo
from .bar import Bar

__all__ = ("Foo", "Bar")
```

This allows users to easily say `from project.datasets import Bar` without worrying about what file `Bar` is defined in.

My problem is that when I go to use Sphinx autodoc, nitpick gives me the following warnings:

```
project.datasets.bar.py:docstring of project.datasets.Bar:1: WARNING: py:class reference target not found: project.datasets.foo.Foo
```

Is there some way to tell Sphinx autodoc that `project.datasets.foo.Foo` is `project.datasets.Foo`? Or some other way to point `project.datasets.foo.Foo` to the documentation for `project.datasets.Foo`? `autodoc-process-bases` looks like a promising hack, but hasn't been released yet.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40018681/407651

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed help! Is there a way to mark this question as a duplicate?