# Need a different module name when using Python's Sphinx automodule directive

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a file layout that looks like:

```
/my_module
    __init__.py
    submodule1.py
    submodule2.py
```

I use Sphinx's `automodule` directive like:

```
.. automodule:: my_module.submodule1
```

It produces documents that say my command name is something like: `my_module.submodule1.my_function`. But my `__init__` pulls `submodule1` into the `my_module` namespace. So what I really want is for the documentation to say `my_module.my_function` instead. Leave out the `submodule1`, since that's not what users are going to use.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/15115514/407651 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/22096187/407651

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, but you can get close.  There is the `~` (tilde) in [standard cross-referencing syntax](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/inline.html#xref-syntax).

> If you prefix the content with ~, the link text will only be the last component of the target. For example,
>
> ```
> :py:meth:`~Queue.Queue.get`
> ```
>
> will refer to `Queue.Queue.get` but only display `get` as the link text. This does not work with all cross-reference roles, but is domain specific.

You might be able to use substitutions or the raw directive, but that would bypass the advantage of using `autodoc` and its directives.