# Sphinx autodoc duplicating module name and function name

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a python module with the following structure:

```
my_mod
|--- __init__.py
|--- mod1
|    |---- __init__.py
     |---- testA.py
     |---- testB.py
     |---- testC.py
```

Inside each testX.py is a **single function that is named testX**. These functions are large so to keep my files manageable I separated testA,B, and C out. To avoid having to access these functions in this manner:

```
import my_mod.mod1.testA.testA
```

My `mod1/__init__.py` file is structured as follows:

```
from .testA import testA
from .testB import testB
from .testC import testC
```

So my functions are now accessible as

```
import my_mod.mod1.testA
```

This behaves as expected. However when I go to autodoc my module with Sphinx the documentation misses this feature in the `__init__` and I end up with my functions being documented as

```
my_mod.mod1.testA.testA(blah, blah, blah)
```

Which is not the actual usage and will fail if called in an actual script.

Is there a way for Sphinx to understand this? Or if not a better way to structure my module to keep my file size small but avoid duplicate names on import?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/15115514/407651

Comment: @mzjn Following the link provided does not solve the issue. Creating the `__all__` in `mod1/__init__.py` keeps the desired import behavior, but the documentation still refers to the "file path" of each function inside testX.py not the import path. The `.. automodule :: my_mod.mod1` does not make a difference either. Setting the `add_module_names=False` does remove all the "file path" information clearing up the documentation a bit... Thanks for looking

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24787344/407651. If it doesn't, please provide a [mcve].