# Change the name of a module in Python Sphinx's autodoc

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am looking to autodoc some functions in a Python module using `autofunction`. Let's say, for example, the functions are defined in `mylib/funcs/a.py` and that file looks something like this:

```python
def myfunc(arg):
    """ My function does something """
    return
```

My intent is to have users call that function from the root of the library rather than at that file/module path. In other words `mylib.myfunc` rather than `mylib.funcs.a.myfunc`.

However, for reasons outside of the scope of this question that I'd rather not get in to, when you do `import mylib; mylib.myfunc` or do `from mylib import myfunc` it doesn't point to the actual function where the docstring is.

I can get the function to auto doc like so:

```rst
..currentmodule:: mylib.funcs.a
..autofunction:: myfunc
```

However, the resulting documentation has a signature that looks like `mylib.funcs.a.myfunc`. I would like it to just be `mylib.myfunc`.

If I wasn't using autodoc I could do something like this in my sphinx docs:

```rst
.. function:: myfunc(arg)
    :module: mylib
```

So I suppose my question is this: Is there a way to "alias" or change the label of a **module** when using autodoc on a function? I have looked at the preprocessing events for processing a docstring and the signature but those don't seem to allow you to change how the module is displayed.

Comment: Do you have a `mylib/__init__.py` file where you import the function? Perhaps these questions will help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15115514/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/22096187/407651

Comment: @mzjn Unfortunately I don't. Or rather the function that is linked in the `__init__.py` points to a different function def/docstring. It's a somewhat bizarre setup but I don't think the `__init__.py` method will work. I did try setting `__module__` in various places, hoping that would work but couldn't make that happen either.

Comment: I think you need to provide a [mcve] that explains your "bizarre" setup.