# How to use sphinx automodule and exposed functions in __init__

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a folder structure that looks like:

```
project/
    mymodule/
        __init__.py
        m1.py
        m2.py
        sub1/
            __init__.py
            s1.py
            s2.py
```

`mymod/__init__.py`:

```
"""The __init__ docstr"""
from m1 import *
from m2 import *
```

`mymod/m1.py`:

```
"""m1 doc str"""
def func1():
    """func1 docstr"""
    return 1
```

`mymod/m2.py`:

```
"""m2 doc str"""
def func2():
    """func2 docstr"""
    return 2
```

`mymod/sub1/__init__.py`:

```
"""The sub1 __init__ docstr"""
from s1 import *
from s2 import *
```

`mymod/sub1/s1.py`:

```
"""s1 docstr"""
def sub1():
    """sub1 docstr"""
    return 3
```

`mymod/sub1/s2.py`:

```
"""s2 docstr"""
def sub2():
    """sub2 docstr"""
    return 4
```

When I use the module directly it seems to be working as expected:

```
>>> import mymod
>>> from mymod import sub1
>>> mymod.func1()
1
>>> sub1.subfunc1()
3
>>> mymod.__doc__
'The __init__ docstr'
>>> mymod.func1.__doc__
'func1 docstr'
```

However, when I go to use the automodule in sphinx (after adding the project folder to my sys.path):

```
.. automodule:: mymod
    :members:

.. automodule:: mymod.sub1
    :members:
```

I get a page with just:

```
The __init__ docstr
The sub1 __init__ docstr
```

It seems to be ignoring the `from m1 import *` type statements...

But, if I copy all of the code directly into the `__init__` files for each module/sub-module I get:

```
The __init__ docstr

mymod.func1()
func1 docstr

mymod.func2()
func2 docstr

The sub1 __init__ docstr

mymod.sub1.sub1()
sub1 docstr

mymod.sub1.sub2()
sub2 docstr
```

Does sphinx `automodule` not work with modules with these sorts of import statements in the `__init__` file or am I missing a more obvious issue?

Ideally, I'd like an output like I get when putting all the code in the **init** (put using import statements instead).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It works if you add an [`__all__`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) list to the `__init__.py` files. For example:

```
"""The __init__ docstr"""

__all__ = ['func1', 'func2']

from m1 import *
from m2 import *
```

Comment: Is this still the way to go? It is not handy, as one has to maintain that list manually for each `__init__.py` just for the sphinx autodoc.

Comment: @fmfreeze Maybe you can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71360980/407651