# Have Sphinx recognize imported classes and functions instead of modules

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Suppose I have a project with the following structure:

```
mypackage
├── mypackage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── someclass.py
│   └── somefunction.py
└── setup.py
```

Then I have `__init__.py` as:

```
from mypackage.someclass import someclass
from mypackage.somefunction import somefunction
```

And `someclass.py` as:

```
class Someclass:
...
```

And `somefunction.py` as:

```
def somefunction:
...
```

It's not possible to "hide" `mypackage.someclass.Someclass` and `mypackage.somefunction.somefunction` from users so only `mypackage.Someclass` and `mypackage.somefunction` are available, right?

But the thing is that Sphinx is actually documentating `mypackage.someclass.Someclass` and `mypackage.somefunction.somefunction` instead of `mypackage.Someclass` and `mypackage.somefunction`.

And in the case of `mypackage.somefunction.somefunction`, it's not even accessible if I import `mypackage`, which is pretty bad.

So, is it possible to have Sphinx document `mypackage.Someclass` and `mypackage.somefunction`? According to what I read on other answers this might be done by editing `__module__` or using `autoclass`, but I wasn't able to archieve this right now

Comment: This looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/15115514/407651

Comment: @mzjn yes! I searched a lot for it but don't remember spoting that question, possibly because the title does not contain `sphinx`. The answer worked there fine, and according to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled I will vote this one to close.

Answer (score 2):

Use autoclass as described in the Sphinx documentation [sphinx.ext.autodoc – Include documentation from docstrings](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html).

In order for autoclass (and any other autodoc feature) to work, the module must be importable.

autodoc will document the API of your module, and you can add docstrings in reStructuredText format as narrative documentation to explain usage.

It's a good idea to have a `docs` directory next to your package directory.

```
mypackage
├── docs
│   ├── conf.py
│   ├── other sphinx stuff
│   └── index.rst
├── mypackage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── someclass.py
│   └── somefunction.py
└── setup.py
```

Organize your `.rst` files within `docs`. Your module is an API, so you could organize your `.rst` files like so:

```
mypackage
├── docs
    └── api
        ├── someclass.rst
        └── somefunction.rst
```

In each of the files in the `api` directory, use the appropriate syntax.

```
.. autoclass:: someclass
.. autofunction:: somefunction
```

There's also several options covered in the aforementioned Sphinx documentation.

Comment: Thanks. My question was more directed at `sphinx-apidoc`, sorry I didn't mentioned it, but anyway, I kinda give up on it (`sphinx-apidoc`) and started doing it manually.

Comment: [sphinx-apidoc relies upon autodoc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-apidoc.html). If you put forth what you tried, expected, and observed with `sphinx-apidoc`, then I might be able to guide you forward.

Comment: Do not worry, the question is actually duplicated, but thank you very much for your answer and being helpful.