# sphinx-apidoc generate documentation for class re-exported in __init__.py

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sphinx-apidoc

In `mypkg/_core.py` I have

```
class SomeClass:
    """Here is my class."""

    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.x = x
```

In `__init__.py` I have

```
from mypkg._core import SomeClass
```

I figure there's a default configuration to avoid documenting everything that's imported, which is fine. In my case, `_core.py` is a private module, and I don't want to document it. I want that documentation to be exported to the top-level `mypkg` module documentation.

I want `SomeClass` to appear in the top-level `mypkg` documentation, but it does not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Have Sphinx recognize imported classes and functions instead of modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264090/have-sphinx-recognize-imported-classes-and-functions-instead-of-modules)