# autodoc: base classes are shown with full name instead of respecting the import

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I hope I find a solution here for this quite intricate problem.

I use sphinx and intersphinx to document my project.

I have a class that inherits from mongoengine.Document.

When I build sphinx docs using sphinx-apidoc and the sphinx-build (via the autogenerated Makefile by sphinx-quickstart), references to mongoengine.Document classes are shown as mongoengine.document.Document, which is actually the correct fully qualified name but this is a problem, because on mongoengine project that class is labelled as mongoengine.Document so intersphinx doesn't link at all.

Is there a way to tell to sphinx to produce information on base classes as they are imported (in my code i have from mongoengine import Document) instead of its full module path?

The following code:

```
from mongoengine import Document, EmbeddedDocumentListField

class MyDocument(Document):
""" my docstring """
```

it produces some html like:

```
class myproj.models.MyDocument(*args, **values) Bases:
mongoengine.document.Document  <-- intersphinx does not find the link to external doc!
```

instead of

```
class myproj.models.MyDocument(*args, **values)
Bases: mongoengine.Document <-- here intersphinx will properly link
```

Comment: Tricky problem. I don't know how to solve it. The bases of a class are determined from the `__bases__` variable. `MyDocument.__bases__` returns `(<class 'mongoengine.document.Document'>,)`.

Comment: Found a workaround. Add `Document.__module__ = "mongoengine"` to your code.

Comment: @mzjn thanks it worked! I think you can make an answer from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__module__` attribute holds the name of the module in which the class was defined. The value of `Document.__module__` is "mongoengine.document".

The attribute is writable, so a workaround is to add the following line to the code:

```
Document.__module__ = "mongoengine"
```