# Sphinx Autodoc Without Submodules

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, sphinx-apidoc

I'm developing a Python package that allows users to import its functions like this:

```
import mymodule
mymodule.afunction()
```

I'm documenting the code with sphinx.  I first ran `sphinx-quickstart`, then I changed `conf.py` to include `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(‘../../src/mymodule’))`.  Then I ran `sphinx-apidoc -f -o source ../src/mymodule` and `make html`.  The directory structure is like this:

```
├── doc
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── build
│   ├── make.bat
│   └── source
│       ├── _static
│       ├── _templates
│       ├── conf.py
│       ├── index.rst
│       ├── modules.rst
│       └── mymodule.rst
└── src
    └── mymodule
        ├── __init__.py
        └── modulecode.py
```

The output lists a "mymodule.modulecode" submodule.  But because of my `__init__py`, users don't explicitly import `modulecode`.

[image]

**Is there an automated way of making the sphinx documentation list the function `mymodule.afunction()` (which is accessed by the user), instead of `mymodule.modulecode.afunction()` (which the user doesn't call)?**

Comment: Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15115514/407651. https://stackoverflow.com/q/47903710/407651

Comment: Thanks for posting the links!  I hadn't seen them; I must have used ineffective search terms when I looked earlier.

Comment: Guided by the above links, I was able to solve the issue.  I needed two steps: 

(1) Add  \_\_all\_\_ to \_\_init\_\_.py, as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/q/15115514/407651.

(2) Delete the submodule section from modules.rst.

I don't think the other posts explicitly mention that apidoc might be adding an submodules section that can safely be deleted.  Later today, I might write an answer to this question that adds this info.  (But if anyone has reasons why that's not worth posting an answer for, that's OK too!)

Comment: Note to anyone reading this later: Step 2 should say "mymodule.rst", NOT "modules.rst".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to mzjn for the helpful comments on my original question!  As discussed in the comments, I needed to do 2 things:

1. Add `__all__=[list of defined functions]` to my `__init__.py`
2. Delete the entire `mymodule.modulecode module` section from `mymodule.rst`.