# Function appears two times in Sphinx autodoc generated documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

### Background information

I generate documentation from docstrings via Sphinx autodoc. There is a function `mypackage.mypackage.foo()` located in source file `mypackage/mypackage.py`. It is imported implicite in the `__init__.py`, so the user can it use as `mypackage.foo()`.

I do manipulate Sphinx autodoc that it generates the docu for `foo()` respecting they way it is imported. This works.

### The problem

The docu about `foo()` is generated twice; once as `mypackage.foo()` and once as `mypackage.mypackage.foo()`.

[image]

### Details

This is the structure of the project:

```
mypackage
├── a.py
├── __init__.py
└── mypackage.py
```

The `__init__.py` does the `import` and then manipulates the `__all__` variable:

```
from .mypackage import *
__all__ = ['foo']  # for alternative see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66996523/4865723
```

And the `mypackage/mypackage.py` defines `foo()`.

Because of that I can do things like that:

```py
import mypackage
mypackage.foo()
```

### Related questions and answers

Here are questions and answers that took me to the current "part solution". Where `mypackage.foo()` appears as expected in the documentation but `mypackage.mypackage.foo()` does not disappear.

- [autodoc: base classes are shown with full name instead of respecting the import](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47903710/4865723)
- [How do I document classes without the module name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15115514/4865723)

Comment: I suppose that there are two `automodule` directives at play here. You need to remove one of them.

Comment: Of course they are because `sphinx-apidoc` generates them this way. I can not edit the rst-files because my edits are overwritten everytime I call `sphinx-apidoc`.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to run sphinx-apidoc over and over again. You can run it once or twice, edit the generated RST files and then add these files to version control. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/28481471/407651.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mzjn gave me the right direction. He is correct that there are two `automodule` directives. So the goal is to make `sphinx-apidoc` (which generates the directives) ignore `mypackage/mypackage.py`.

For that make it a "private module" with modyfing it's filename starting with an underscore (`_`).

The resulting project structure:

```
mypackage
├── a.py
├── __init__.py
└── _mypackage.py
```

And the import in `__init__.py` need to modified to `from ._mypackage import *`.