# Sphinx autodoc, remove module name when is the same as class name

Tags: python, package, documentation, python-sphinx

I am developing a python package with some sub-packages and modules. I have a few modules that are quite large and would like to split them. I will end up having a single class per module in that particular subpackage. To give an example imagine:

```
package
├── __init__.py
├── subpackage_1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── foo.py
│   └── bar.py
├── subpackage_2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── module_x.py
├── module_y.py
└── ..
```

Modules foo and bar have only one class:

```
foo.py:

class Foo:
   pass

bar.py:

class Bar:
   pass
```

To access these classes in an easy way without double names, the init file in subpackage_1:

```
__init__.py:

from .foo import Foo
from .bar import Bar
def __dir__():
   return ['Foo', 'Bar']
```

While coding, after importing this package,  classes can be accessed as: `package.subpackage_1.Foo`. When I generate my sphinx html documentation with autodoc, these classes show up as `package.subpackage_1.foo.Foo`.

How can I automatically remove the module name when it is the same as the class name everywhere in my html documentation and show `package.subpackage_1.Foo`? This would be coherent with how a user uses this library with tab completion.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/15115514/407651

Comment: I'll check that and come back if it doesn't answer my question. I wonder how I didn't find it before!

Comment: Are you sure this is still working on newer sphinx versions? I am trying, but so far the module name always show up :/

Comment: If the answers to the linked question do not help, please show us exactly what you are doing ([mcve]).

Comment: Yes I'll prepare that and add it to my post!